# You have not accepted the license agreements.[Android SDK Platform 23]

Tags: android, react-native, sdk

I am working with React-Native, when I run the `react-native run-android`
run command I get this error

> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK
>   components:[Android SDK Platform 23, Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1].

I have Android Studio with SDK version 26 and Android SDK Build-Tools 26 installed.

Why does react give this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try follow this comment and try if it solves your issue? https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/1726#issuecomment-279164447

Comment: Could you please see [my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201497/you-have-not-accepted-the-licenses-arguments-after-run-sdkmanager-bat-licenses)

Answer (score 1):

the error show that you not accept license on build tools v23.0.1
you need to accept that license. do following things

```
Android\sdk\tools\bin>sdkmanager.bat "build-tools;23.0.1"
```