# react-native run-android fails: Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-sdk-tools

You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
[Android SDK Platform 23, Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1].
Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

Comment: I had this issue too. Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45364498/you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-android-sdk-platform-23) and fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy licenses folder inside C:/Users/your user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/licenses and past to C:/Users/your user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/tools folder.

Now run react-native run-android

It worked for me